# Random float in C using getrandom

Tags: c, random, floating-point

I'm trying to generate a random floating point number in between 0 and 1 (whether it's on [0,1] or [0,1) shouldn't matter for me). Every question online about this seems to involves the `rand()` call, seeded with `time(NULL)`, but I want to be able to invoke my program more than once a second and get different random numbers every time. This lead me to the getrandom syscall in Linux, which pulls from /dev/urandom. I came up with this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
  uint32_t r = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    syscall(SYS_getrandom, &r, sizeof(uint32_t), 0);
    printf("%f\n", ((double)r)/UINT32_MAX);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

My question is simply whether or not I'm doing this correctly. It appears to work, but I'm worried that I'm misusing something, and there are next to no examples using getrandom() online.

Comment: Well, your method can surely produce 1. Usually `[0,1)` is wanted Also it might (=will) have less precision than IEEE double which has 53 bit mantissa.

Comment: Rather than a `syscall()`, could you not open `fopen('/dev/urandom', 'rb')` and read 4 bytes?  or then put that into `srand()`?

Comment: A more portable method is to open `/dev/urandom` and `read(2)` from it.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala That should be fine since I think I'm actually going to end up using these as floats. But if I did want all 53, would making `r` a `uint64_t` and masking with `0x001FF..FF` do the trick?

Comment: @chux I'd rather avoid dealing with files, since I don't have to worry about portability, and using the syscall is easier/less prone to failure I believe. Using that to seed `srand()` is a good idea I hadn't thought of, though.

Comment: @user3030010, what makes you think the syscall would be less prone to failure than reading from the urandom device would be?

Comment: This method will have a probability of generating a NAN or an infinite. You should check if the output float is valid for your case of use.

Comment: @xvan it can't produce a NAN or infinite, with 64-bit IEEE double.

Comment: Side note: "I want to be able to invoke my program more than once a second "... No, you shouldn't be seeding *rand()* every time you call it. Only once. You might be destroying a carefully constructed distrubution of random numbers otherwise, and repeated seeding doesn't make *rand()* any more random.

Comment: You could produce an NaN or an infinity if you populated a double or float with random bits, but nobody is suggesting that.  If you generate an unsigned *integer* filled with random bits, convert to `double`, then divide by the maximum possible value then you reliably get a `double` in the closed interval [0,1].

Comment: @tofro S/he's not talking about repeated seeding, but repeatedly running the program, where the program seeds once on startup.

Comment: My bad, thought that he was casting a pointer, I read it bad.

Comment: Why don't you use `#include <sys/random.h>`?

Comment: @Geremia Because it didn't exist when I asked the question :) https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/703136/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OP has 2 issues:

1. How to started the sequence very randomly.
2. How to generate a `double` on the [0...1) range.

The usual method is to take a very random source like `/dev/urandom` or the result from the `syscall()` or maybe even `seed = time() ^ process_id;` and seed via `srand()`.  Then call `rand()` as needed.

Below includes a quickly turned method to generate a uniform `[0.0 to 1.0)` (linear distribution).  But like all random generating functions, really good ones are base on extensive study.  This one simply calls `rand()` a few times based on `DBL_MANT_DIG` and `RAND_MAX`,

[Edit] Original `double rand_01(void)` has a weakness in that it only generates a 2^52 different `double`s  rather than 2^53.  It has been amended.  Alternative: a `double` version of `rand_01_ld(void)` far below.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

double rand_01(void) {
  assert(FLT_RADIX == 2); // needed for DBL_MANT_DIG
  unsigned long long limit = (1ull << DBL_MANT_DIG) - 1;
  double r = 0.0;
  do {
    r += rand();
    // Assume RAND_MAX is a power-of-2 - 1
    r /= (RAND_MAX/2 + 1)*2.0;
    limit = limit / (RAND_MAX/2 + 1) / 2;
  } while (limit);

  // Use only DBL_MANT_DIG (53) bits of precision.
  if (r < 0.5) {
    volatile double sum = 0.5 + r;
    r = sum - 0.5;
  }
  return r;
}

int main(void) {
  FILE *istream = fopen("/dev/urandom", "rb");
  assert(istream);
  unsigned long seed = 0;
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < sizeof seed; i++) {
    seed *= (UCHAR_MAX + 1);
    int ch = fgetc(istream);
    assert(ch != EOF);
    seed += (unsigned) ch;
  }
  fclose(istream);
  srand(seed);

  for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {
    printf("%f\n", rand_01());
  }

  return 0;
}
```

---

If one wanted to extend to an even wider FP, unsigned wide integer types may be insufficient.  Below is a portable method that does not have that limitation.

```
long double rand_01_ld(void) {
  // These should be calculated once rather than each function call
  // Leave that as a separate implementation problem
  // Assume RAND_MAX is power-of-2 - 1
  assert((RAND_MAX & (RAND_MAX + 1U)) == 0);
  double rand_max_p1 = (RAND_MAX/2 + 1)*2.0;
  unsigned BitsPerRand = (unsigned) round(log2(rand_max_p1));
  assert(FLT_RADIX != 10);
  unsigned BitsPerFP = (unsigned) round(log2(FLT_RADIX)*LDBL_MANT_DIG);

  long double r = 0.0;
  unsigned i;
  for (i = BitsPerFP; i >= BitsPerRand; i -= BitsPerRand) {
    r += rand();
    r /= rand_max_p1;
  }
  if (i) {
    r += rand() % (1 << i);
    r /= 1 << i;
  }
  return r;
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about the effect on the precision of starting with more random bits than the result has mantissa bits.  Why not just generate `DBL_MANTISSA_BITS` random bits in a suitable integer, convert that to `double`, and use `ldexp()` to scale it into the range `[0, 1)`?

Comment: @John Bollinger The challenge is to do "generate DBL_MANTISSA_BITS random bits" in a _portable_ fashion with regard to  `RAND_MAX` and `DBL_MANT_DIG`.  Sure would like code to, at compile time, know the integer constant of `log2(RAND_MAX + 1)` without any range error or other issues.  Even `RAND_MAX +1u` can overflow.  Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: @John Bollinger 2nd method added (for `long double`) that does not use extra random bits.

Comment: Nice.  I'd give you another +1 if I could.

Comment: Another informative post. Anything against `float.h` and `limits.h`?

Comment: @David C. Rankin `float.h  limits.h` were late to the party, they were not meant to be "excluded".

Comment: Note: If `FLT_RADIX == 10` (rare platforms that uses decimal floating point), the challenge to portability make an even distribution of FP numbers `[0...1)`  is harder.  This answer would need re-work on those platforms.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to generate doubles, the following algorithm could be of use:

CPython [generates random numbers](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/513f40a9abfc00b7de1f36eb780c2cf47169cf2a/Modules/_randommodule.c) using the following algorithm (*I* changed the function name, typedefs and return values, but algorithm remains the same):

```
double get_random_double() {
    uint32_t a = get_random_uint32_t() >> 5;
    uint32_t b = get_random_uint32_t() >> 6;
    return (a * 67108864.0 + b) * (1.0 / 9007199254740992.0);
}
```

The source of that algorithm is a Mersenne Twister 19937 random number generator by Takuji Nishimura and Makoto Matsumoto. Unfortunately the original link mentioned in the source is not available for download any longer.

The comment on this function in CPython notes the following:

> [this function] is the function named genrand_res53 in the original code;
>   generates a random number on [0,1) with 53-bit resolution; note that
>   `9007199254740992 == 2**53`; I assume they're spelling "`/2**53`" as
>   multiply-by-reciprocal in the (likely vain) hope that the compiler will
>   optimize the division away at compile-time.  `67108864` is `2**26`.  In
>   effect, a contains 27 random bits shifted left 26, and `b` fills in the
>   lower 26 bits of the 53-bit numerator.
>
> The orginal code credited Isaku Wada for this algorithm, 2002/01/09

---

Simplifying from that code, if you want to create a `float` fast, you should mask the bits of `uint32_t` with `(1 << FLT_MANT_DIG) - 1` and divide by `(1 << FLT_MANT_DIG)` to get the proper `[0, 1)` interval:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <float.h>

int main() {
    uint32_t r = 0;
    float result;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        syscall(SYS_getrandom, &r, sizeof(uint32_t), 0);
        result = (float)(r & ((1 << FLT_MANT_DIG) - 1)) / (1 << FLT_MANT_DIG);
        printf("%f\n", result);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Since it can be assumed that your Linux has a C99 compiler, we can use `ldexpf` instead of that division:

```
#include <math.h>

result = ldexpf(r & ((1 << FLT_MANT_DIG) - 1), -FLT_MANT_DIG);
```

To get the closed interval `[0, 1]`, you can do the slightly less efficient

```
result = ldexpf(r % (1 << FLT_MANT_DIG), -FLT_MANT_DIG);
```

---

To generate lots of good quality random numbers fast, I'd just use the system call to fetch enough data to seed a PRNG or CPRNG, and proceed from there.